# A single word for "not enrolled"

Tags: word-request, synonyms

Are there any other words which give the meaning **not enrolled**?

I am searching for a single word which means **never being enrolled in the first place, or not being a member of some class/school/institution** etc.

I know of the word **unenrolled** but I don't know whether it's correct or not as I cannot find it's meaning in some dictionaries like *Oxford advanced learners dictionaries, Cambridge dictionary* etc. Though I have found its meaning as *to undo the enrollment of*, in some dictionaries. I have found some other words like *disenroll* which imply the same meaning.

Suppose I want to say students who are not enrolled in a class, how can I say it using alternative for "not enrolled"?

But I can't find any word which implies the meaning ***never enrolled in the first place***.

Are there any words which fits in the context? If so, can anyone please tell me which words I can use instead of *not enrolled*?

Comment: What's wrong with 'not enrolled'? - it describes the situation perfectly, though it doesn't distinguish between 'non-members' & 'ex-members'.

Comment: And what's wrong with nonmember? Questions asking for lists of words aren't really a great fit for this format.

Comment: To be "unenrolled" is a somewhat colloquial way to say "**removed** from the rolls".  It's not the same as never being enrolled in the first place, or not being a member of some community.  There are several words that may fit, but a lot depends on the context.  What exactly are they not members of?

Comment: @OmkarReddy  I've never heard anything but, "Students who are **not enrolled** in the class."  That is the most idiomatic English expression.  Anything else would probably sound strange.

Comment: The full OED lists "unenrolled" ([OED Online](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/212900) - paywalled, but many libraries and other educational institutions provide access to members), and has done since the 1921 first edition.

Comment: @OmkarReddy  *unregistered*, possibly, but this means something different.  As I said, "not enrolled" is what everyone actually *uses*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think there is one. I work closely with a registrar at an institution of higher learning, and students might be ***admitted** into a program, ***enrolled*** in a course or program, or ***registered*** for a class, but I don’t know of any single word that covers “never enrolled” better than the phrase “not enrolled” (which could mean that the student was enrolled at one time, but has since disenrolled) or “never enrolled”.

Sometimes English just doesn’t have a word for something you’d like to say in a single word.

Answer (score 2):

The single word you may be looking for might be

> **non-enrolled**
>
> [Non-enrolled Student Policy:
>
>   Students who wish to remain active
>   in their program 
>   but do not enroll for classes in either the fall or 
>   spring semester and are not on a Leave of Absence will be considered non-enrolled.](https://www.unmc.edu/media/studentservices/docs/non-enrolled-student-policy112113.pdf)